# Why does the ul element's padding area and the children separated in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a to-do app following this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wCpkOk2uCg). I should separate the area between to-do task and completed task using padding. I hope the padding area of `#completed` moves with `#completed`'s children, but it is always at the top of `.container`. How do I merge the padding and items?
[The location of the padding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWlN.png)

As far as I've been searching about css positioning, I think, setting the position both of `#todo` and `#completed` relative is right. But it doesn't work. I also tried setting the position of `#complete` only like the tutorial. It also doesn't work.

This is the html code of the `.container` which includes `#todo` and `#completed` area.

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Uncompleted tasks -->
    <ul class ="todo" id="todo">

    </ul>

    <!-- Completed tasks -->
    <ul class="todo" id="completed"></ul>
</div>
```

This is the css code what I set the position. I didn't set the position of `.container`.(I modified background color and opacity for verifying of padding area.)

```css
ul.todo#todo {
    position:relative;
}

ul.todo#completed:not(:empty) {
    position:relative;
    padding:60px 0 0 0;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.3;
}

ul.todo#completed:not(:empty):before {
    content:'';
    width:150px;
    height:1px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:50%;
    margin:0 0 0 -75px;
}
```

and this is the full css code(https://github.com/JaeraeKim/todoList/blob/master/app/resources/css/style.css)

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `margin` instead of padding if you are trying to add space between these elements. So a `margin-bottom` on `#todo` or a `margin-top` on `#completed` should move them apart.

Padding keeps the element the same size but "shrinks" it into its own space while margin creates space around it that is reserved as white space.

Comment: If this answers your question, can you mark it as solved to increase visibility/take it off the question board?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried change padding to `margin-top` on `#completed` and I can click that area where I cannot when it was padding. However, it still separated. I guess the `position` makes problem. I'd like to ask you what do you think.

Comment: Could you create a loom video or attach more complete HTML so I can better understand the new issue?

Comment: Okay. Please check the full HTML code [here](https://github.com/JaeraeKim/todoList/blob/master/app/index.html).

Comment: I found the cause. I... didn't write the semicolon... I apologize for my carelessness and really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Just seeing these so apologies, glad you got it though!